# Phonegap Webview - Show contacts list for Android Only

Tags: android, cordova

I have setup and installed Phonegap on my Eclipse environment together with Android SDKs. Everything seems to be working fine except when I install additional phonegap plugin [https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ContactView] with the aim of viewing my contacts list.

---

**Here are the instruction:**

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ContactView

---

now how do I pull the list into my index file under assets/www

Help Please

---

Here is my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap Demo With JQuery Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pgandjqm-style-override.css" type="text/css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="calllog.js"></script>

    </head>
  <body onload="init();">
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome to Stellar</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"><script type="text/javascript"> window.plugins.CallLog.list('all', successCallBack, failCallBack);</script></div>
    <div data-role="content"><a href="tel:411" data-role="button">Call 411</a>
    <div data-role="button" onclick="window.plugins.CallLog.list('all', successCallBack, failCallBack);">Beep</div>
    <div data-role="button" onclick="beep();">Beep</div>

    <div id="viewport" class="viewport" style="display:none;">       
      <img style="width:60px;height:60px" id="test_img" src="" />
    </div> 
    </div><!-- end jqm content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Thanks for being around</h1>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The files below should make it work. BTW, I'm not sure what's in your calllog.js, but there definitely needs to be a ContactView.js in index.html.  See the following files and screenshot of the full app running:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap Demo With JQuery Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pgandjqm-style-override.css" type="text/css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ContactView.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
      var successCallBack = function(args) {
        alert (JSON.stringify(args));
        };
      var failCallBack = function(args) {
        alert (JSON.stringify(args));
        };
      </script>

    </head>
  <body onload="init();">
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome to Stellar</h1> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"><a href="tel:411" data-role="button">Call 411</a>
    <div data-role="button" onclick="window.plugins.ContactView.show('all', successCallBack, failCallBack);">Beep</div>
    <div data-role="button" onclick="beep();">Beep</div>

    <div id="viewport" class="viewport" style="display:none;">       
      <img style="width:60px;height:60px" id="test_img" src="" />
    </div> 
    </div><!-- end jqm content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Thanks for being around</h1>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

ContactView.js

```
var ContactView = function() {};

ContactView.prototype.show = function(cmd, successCallback, failCallback) {

    function success(args) {
        successCallback(args);
    }

    function fail(args) {
        failCallback(args);
    }

    return PhoneGap.exec(function(args) {
        success(args);
    }, function(args) {
        fail(args);
    }, 'ContactView', '', []);
};

/**
 * Load ChildBrowser
 */
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("ContactView", new ContactView());
});
```

Also, res/xml/plugins.xml needs the following line added:

```
  <plugin name="ContactView" value="com.rearden.ContactView"/>
```

Next is the screenshot showing the directory structure, changed files and running app:

[image: Screen shot of running app]